# Nginx: Static js and css contents are not loading

Tags: azure, nginx, reverse-proxy, informatica

I'm trying to use Nginx as a reverse proxy for an Informatica application.

I have the following URLs:

```bash
EDC MetaDex URL: https://x.cloudapp.azure.com:48090/login
Admin Console URL: https://x.cloudapp.azure.com:8443/administrator
EDC Ldmcatalog URL: https://x.cloudapp.azure.com:9085/ldmcatalog
EDC Ldmadmin URL: https://x.cloudapp.azure.com:9085/ldmadmin
```

Only the first URL is not working. The rest are working fine.

Here is my Nginx configuration:

```bash
# information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

  sendfile off;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_timeout 65;
  types_hash_max_size 4096;

  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
  # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
  # for more information.
  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

  map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    '' close;
  }

  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
  proxy_connect_timeout 90;
  proxy_send_timeout 90;
  proxy_read_timeout 90;
  proxy_buffering off;
  proxy_request_buffering off;


  server {
    server_name demoserver.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/infa.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/infa.error.log;

    location /monitoring {
      proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8443/monitoring;

    }
    location /administrator {
      proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8443/administrator;

    }

    location /login {
      proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:48090/login;
      location ~* \.(css|js)$ {
        expires 30d;
        # root ?
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
      }

    }
    location /ldmadmin {
      proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:9085/ldmadmin;

    }
    location /ldmcatalog {
      proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:9085/ldmcatalog;

    }
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate "/opt/certificate/certificate.crt";
    ssl_certificate_key "/opt/certificate/private.key";
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    ssl_ciphers PROFILE=SYSTEM;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  }
  server {
    if ($host = demoserver.com) {
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }


    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on default_server;
    server_name demoserver.com;
    return 404;
  }

}
```

The problem is that the static JS and CSS content is not loading and gives a 404 error if I use `https://demoserver.com/login`, whereas it runs fine on 127.0.0.1. The Informatica application is installed at `/opt/Informatica`, and I cannot find these static files anywhere in this directory. What am I missing?

[image: chrome network tab]